# Альтернатива подключения к базе данных Mysq

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!Дело  в слудующем.

Подключаюсь к базе данных которая находится на хосте .Все ок проблем нету )
Подключение происходит следущим образом :
`клиент <==>скрипт(Php)<==>Сервер`
Проблем нет все ок!Но я хочу подключаться к базе данных через саму Java не использая скрипты ,на сколько это возможно ?методы(Способы),и является ли это хорошим или плохим примером(и почему).Знаю вопрос может порадить споры но если каждый выдаст по зацепке в сумме это будет знание!Благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложно в этом нету, если у Вас есть доступ к настройке хоста. Программа сервера базы данных MySQL должно быть настроена на прием входящих соединений по IP адресу хоста. Дело в том, что чаще всего такая функция в целях безопасности отключается администратором сервера.

Если необходимая настройка имеется, то можно подключаться напрямую. Например, сервер "sample.com":

```
import java.sql.*;
class MysqlCon{
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:mysql://sample.com:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
     //database name, username and password  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
    while(rs.next())  
      System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
    con.close();  
   }
     catch(Exception e)
   { System.out.println(e);}  
   }
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо,а есть ли сущестенно разница между таким подключение и подключением через скрипт?что надежнее?)

Comment: Надежнее более простое - чем меньше звеньев в цепи, тем меньше возможностей для отказа. Но тут не последнюю роль играет вопрос безопасности - я бы предпочел через скрипт, чем открывать порт базы данных на реальном IP адресе. А PHP скрипты достаточно шустрые и стабильные. Хотя, если у Вас на сервере PHP больше нигде не используется, то держать его ради трансляции наверно смысла нет. В любом случае выбор за вами.

Comment: да на самом деле я знал про JDBC  для удаленного управления

Comment: Но от него решил отказаться сразу ,при декомпиляции проекта уже слишком много дыр он за собой оставляет .В руках умелого это как то даже страшно )мой уровень пока не позволяет писать на дажа безопаснее )поэтому буду работать со скриптом )но огромное спасибо)